# Why can I not use ClientWebSocket in a Shared Project in VS 2015?

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am trying to port my iPhone App that I coded using Xamarin to Cross-Platform (especially for Android).
I created a new native Portable App in VS2015 and managed to put all the shared code into the Portable project, leaving me with only the Views in each app.

Now I got stuck with the WebSocket. I can easily create a new WebSocketClient in my Android App, as I can in my iOS App.

If i try *using System.Net.WebSockets* in my portable app it's not found, and wants me to set a new iOS or Mono.Android assembly reference. Is there a way to use the WebSocket in the shared project or do I have to code it for each app on its own?
Thanks.

Edit: Thanks for the input. I tried using Websockets.PCL but had problems with binary data as my server didn't recieve the data as I expected it to. It worked fine with the WebSocketClient though.

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http may cover your needs for most mobile applications unless you really want to work with sockets - is that an option to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:
[C# Websockets for all platforms using native bridges](https://github.com/NVentimiglia/WebSockets.Pcl)

NuGet: [WebSocket Portable (PCL for Xamarin) 1.0.6.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebSocket.Portable.Core/1.0.6.1)

Answering your question: You have to provide a platform-specific implementation and a cross-platform interface for WebSocket.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a PCL compatible socket library like [WebSocket.Portable](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebSocket.Portable.Core/1.0.6.1)

Comment: Didn't work as expected with bytes as I wanted it to, thank you though